# Ограничить число загрузок с сайта?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

хочу ограничить число скачиваний с сайта для каждого пользователя, допустим в месяц 10 загрузок
какой плагин посоветуйте
и чтобы незарегистрированные вообще не могли скачивать

Answer (score 0):

В репозитории WordPress есть раздел плагинов, а там поиском можно найти массу плагинов по ключевому слову [download](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/search/download/).

Один из наиболее известных плагинов из этой серии - [Download Manager](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/download-manager/).